# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value in mongoose operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have used a middleware called checktoken in every routes except login route in my code . when i hit login url it logged me in where there is to token checked. but now if i wish to go to any route after logging in it restricts me inside checkToken middleware.i have used jsonwebtoken module to generate token and verify it.but my code failed to find users.here is my checktoken middle ware code

```
if (token) {
    try {
        var decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(token, jwt_key);
        req.user = decoded.user;///
         console.log(req.user._id);// i get id here and from this id i can find user in database 
        UserSchema.findOne({
                _id: req.user._id
            })///this query failed finding result
            .exec(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);//error gets output in the console.
                    res.status(500);
                    return res.json({
                        result: err
                    });
                }
                if (result) {
                    return next();
                } else {
                    res.status(400);
                    return res.json({
                        message: "The user does not exists"
                    });
                }
            });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(403);
        res.json({
            message: "Invalid Token"
        });
    }
} else {
    res.status(401);
    res.json({
        message: "No token provided"
    });
}
```

the error message i get in console is

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5875d76e1df97635623061c5" at path "_id" for model "User"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5875d76e1df97635623061c5" at path "_id" for model "User"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"5875d76e1df97635623061c5"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '5875d76e1df97635623061c5',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'User',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'myschoolbus_demo',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: [Object],
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [Object],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: [Object],
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        s: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'users',
        collectionName: 'users',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     insertMany: [Function] } }
```

i cannot figure out where i am wrong. any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should check the type of req.user._id and then try to convert that into object

Comment: You're using UserSchema? Not model?

Answer (score 0):

Strip quotes from your id. Your error says:

```
stringValue: '"5875d76e1df97635623061c5"',
```

See the `"` at start and end? It's part of the string. I don't know if your middleware, or frontend or whoever puts it, so either strip it yourself or pass it before.

```
Try this:

UserSchema.findOne({
  _id: req.user._id.replace(/"/g, '')
})
```

Comment: Exactly the same? You didn't strip quotes then. What do you see when you type: 
    `console.log('"5875d76e1df97635623061c5"' === '"5875d76e1df97635623061c5"'.replace(/"/g, ''))`?

Comment: i get clearly 5875d76e1df97635623061c5 in my console not "5875d76e1df97635623061c5"

Comment: Well I'm not sure then. When I repeat the same thing with my both mongoose and MongoDB shell directly, I get the expected (errors for extra quotes, working find/insert when not.
Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(decoded.user, null, 2))` and paste what you get back?

Comment: And the same for `req.user`?

Comment: And typeof req.user._id?